# Django 2.2 NoReverseMatch error, kwargs returns blank string?

Tags: python, django

I get a NoReverseMatch error with a blank string for kwargs. Am I doing something wrong in the models.py file that doesn't save the username associated with the post?

> NoReverseMatch at /groups/posts/in/nasa-rocks/ Reverse for 'for_user'
>   with keyword arguments '{'username': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['posts/by/(?P[^/]+)/$']

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

import misaka

from groups.models import Group

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='posts',on_delete='CASCADE')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,related_name='posts',null=True,blank=True,on_delete='CASCADE')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:detail',kwargs={'username':self.user.username,'pk':self.pk})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        unique_together = ['user','message']
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='list'),
    path('create/',views.PostCreateView.as_view(),name='create'),
    path('by/<username>/',views.UserPosts.as_view(),name='for_user'),
    path('by/<username>/<pk>/',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
    path('delete/<pk>/',views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),name='delete')
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from django.views import generic
from django.http import Http404

from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin

from . import models
from . import forms

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

# Create your views here.

class PostListView(SelectRelatedMixin,generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user','group')

class UserPosts(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = 'posts/user_post_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            self.post_user = User.objects.prefetch_related("posts").get(
                username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        else:
            return self.post_user.posts.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["post_user"] = self.post_user
        return context

class PostDetailView(SelectRelatedMixin,generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user','group')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,SelectRelatedMixin,generic.CreateView):

    fields = ('message','group')
    model = models.Post

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,SelectRelatedMixin,generic.DeleteView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user','group')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:list')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

        def delete(self,*args,**kwargs):
            message.success(self.request,'Post Deleted')
            return super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

_post.html:

```
<div class="post media">
  <h3>{{post.message_html|safe}}</h3>
  <div class="media-body">
    <strong>{{post.user.username}}</strong>
    <h5 class="media-heading">
      <span class="username">
                <a href="{% url 'posts:for_user' username=post.user.username %}">@{{ post.user.username }}</a>
            </span>
            <time class="time">
                <a href="{% url 'posts:detail' username=post.user.username pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.created_at }}</a>
            </time>
      {% if post.group %}
      <span class="group-name">in <a href="#">{{ post.group.name }}</a></span>
      {% endif %}

    </h5>
    <div class="media-footer">
      {% if user.is_authenticated and post.user == user %}
        <a href="{% url 'posts:delete' pk=post.pk %}" title='delete' class="btn btn-simple">
          <span class="fas fa-trash-alt text-danger" aria-hidden="True"></span>
          <span class="text-danger icon-label">Delete</span>
        </a>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you see the username between `<strong>` tags?

Comment: @Selcuk no, it doesn't show up there either.

Comment: That's your problem then, it has nothing to do with urls. Do you have a post? Can you see any `post.message_html` text? Also you haven't posted the urls & views responsible for the URL that the error occurs in: `groups/posts/in/nasa-rocks/`

Comment: Which view is responsible for rendering _post.html?

Comment: @Selcuk I can see something if I hard-code in a username, but not using the variable post.user.username

Comment: @R.Manes did you solve your problem?

Comment: Until you show what is responsible for rendering _post.html we cannot help you.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand problem is empty username. Default pattern requires it to be at least one symbol `['posts/by/(?P[^/]+)/$']`. So likely you didn't fetch model properly or there is no user for post.

Error by the way is pretty verbose on this. It shows pattern and arguments, you need to read it more careful.